# Statistics of HDN on groups without risk factors

Tags: infant, vitamin-k, prophylaxis

To prevent hemorrhagic disease of the newborn (HDN) it seems to be standard that newborns get a neonatal vitamin K prophylaxis (oral or parenteral).

I know that statistically about 1 of 30000 (otherwise healthy) newborn has HDN if no vitamin K prophylaxis was given.

How does this number change if one looks only at cases with no obvious risk factors except breast feeding i.e.

- unproblematic natural birth (in particular nor birth trauma)
- successful breast feeding in the first hour after birth
- healthy balanced diet of the mother during and post pregnancy
- mother didn't consume alcohol or smoked during and post pregnancy
- mother didn't take drugs or medicaments during and post pregnancy